# Upgrading parachain runtime for async backing "Timing by Block Number" question?

Tags: parachain, async-backing

After reviewing this [guide](https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/maintain-guides-async-backing#phase-3---activate-async-backing) on upgrading the runtime of a parachain for async backing, I have a few questions regarding the "Timing by Block Number" section of phase 3, it mentions that modifying the block duration for parachains that measure time in terms of its own block number could produce issues, how can I check if our parachain is affected by this?

It also mentions that for parachains affected by this it might be preferable to increase velocity, instead of modifying block duration, does this mean increasing the BLOCK_PROCESSING_VELOCITY value to 2?

Finally it mentions that another strategy to deal with this issue is to rely on relay chain block numbers for timing, how would this be done?